# SQL query to fetch all rows, if duplicate column value present then select only one row based on column value

Tags: sql

I have a 3 tables called signals, Units, Datatypes

| SignalID | SignalName | UnitID | DataTypeID | Min | Max | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BrdgVltg | 1 | 1 | 0 | 32000 | 1 |
| 2 | BattVltg | 1 | 2 | 0 | 65000 | 1 |
| 3 | SigCurr | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1000 | 1 |
| 4 | BattVltg | 1 | 2 | 0 | 65000 | 2 |
| 5 | SigCurr | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1000 | 2 |
| 6 | SigCurr | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1000 | 3 |

| UnitID | UnitName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Volt |
| 2 | ampere |

| DataTypeID | DataType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Float |
| 2 | Integer |
| 3 | Enum |

now I need a query which will give me unique row from all tables based on column "SignalName" and if duplicate value is present in column "SignalName" then it should give me that row which has highest "Version".
for above case the output table will be

| SignalID | SignalName | UnitName | DataType | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BrdgVltg | Volt | float | 0 | 32000 |
| 4 | BattVltg | Volt | Integer | 0 | 65000 |
| 6 | SigCurr | Ampere | Enum | 0 | 1000 |

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: This is the `group by` sql functionality: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the highest version of each SignalName using `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`, and then join this dataset to your table:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select SignalName, MAX(Version) as max_version
  from mytable
  group by SignalName
) as s on s.SignalName = t.SignalName and s.max_version = t.version;
```

[Demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/1N1HToXU)

---

After your edit, here is how to join tables together :

```
select t.SignalID, t.SignalName, UnitName, DataType, Min, Max
from signals t
inner join (
  select SignalName, MAX(Version) as max_version
  from signals
  group by SignalName
) as s on s.SignalName = t.SignalName and s.max_version = t.version
inner join Units u on u.UnitID = t.UnitID
inner join Datatypes d on d.DataTypeID = t.DataTypeID
```

Comment: I have modified the question with adding some more connecting tables, could you please help me now

Comment: I see you've heavily edited your question! Instead of editing your question after it was answered, you should have created a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SignalName,ID,Min,Max,MAX(Version) from signals group by SignalName
```

Please avoid using version as column name as it is a function definition in sql.

Comment: `version` isn't a ISO/ANSI SQL standard reserved word. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` window function, over partition by SignalID, to get the row with the highest version number for each SignalID:

```
select s.SignalID, s.SignalName, u.UnitName, d.DataType, s.Min, s.Max
from
(
  select s2.*,
         row_number() over (partition by SignalID order by version desc) rn
  from signals s2
) s
inner join Units u on u.UnitID = s.UnitID
inner join Datatypes d on d.DataTypeID = s.DataTypeID
where s.rn = 1
```

> Conforms to SQL-2016
>  The following features outside Core SQL-2016
> are used:
>  T611, Elementary OLAP operations
>  F591, Derived
> tables